# How do i flash a message in django?

Tags: django

So, I want my django app to notify users of certain events through flashed messages. Like, an error message or a success message. I know there is a built in `flash` method in flask. But is there any equivalent in django? If yes, then can you please show me how to use it and style it using bootstrap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django messages framework works really well and is easy to use with bootstrap as well.

Step 1: Place a message at the point in the flow where you want the message to fire off. This is an example of a message fired when a form successfully saves form data:

```
 if form.is_valid():
        for fs in formsets:
            if fs.is_valid():
                # Messages test start
                messages.success(request, "Profile updated successfully!")
                # Messages test end
                fs.save()
            else:
                messages.error(request, "It didn't save!")
```

When the message is fired it doesn't automatically appear. But it's stored in a queue.

Step 2: Add the code in your template to show the messages:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This above is the simples possible implementation. An example of the same thing but with bootrstrap toasts would look something like this:

```
{% if messages %} 
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-autohide="false">
            <div class="toast-header">
                <div class="toast-square"></div>&nbsp;
                <strong class="mr-auto">Accounts</strong>
                <small>Changes saved</small>
                <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="toast-body">
            {{ message }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/) shipped with Django.